# Date format is changing while fetching data using Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to fetch and load data to a kendo grid using some parameters. But when I am using date parameter, format of date is changing hence showing me wrong dates in server side.

As an example as a parameter I am using: new Date("April 01, 2016"). But in server side it becomes 04/01/2016 which is wrong.

```js
function passFilterCstDetails() {

        var statemenetInquiryParameter = {};

        statemenetInquiryParameter.isPrintZero = true;
        statemenetInquiryParameter.isPrintPayments = true;
        statemenetInquiryParameter.isPrintAdjust = true;
        statemenetInquiryParameter.cst_stmt_from = new Date("April 01, 2016");
        statemenetInquiryParameter.cst_stmt_to = new Date("April 12, 2016");
        statemenetInquiryParameter.customerCode = 007;

        return {
            statemenetInquiryParameter: statemenetInquiryParameter
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ServicePROWeb.ServiceProWCFService.CstTran>()
                            .Name("gridCustomerCstTranDetails")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_inv_date).Title("Invoice Date").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Format(Session["DisplayFormat_GridDate"].ToString()).Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_type).Title("Type").Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_ih_invno).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Filterable(false).Title("Invoice Number").Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_dr_amount).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Filterable(false).Title("Debit").Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_cr_amount).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Filterable(false).Title("Credit").Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_dr_balance).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Filterable(false).Title("Balance").Width(80);
                            })
                            .Selectable()
                            .Sortable()
                            .Scrollable()
                            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "cursor:pointer;height:auto;width:auto;margin-top: 0px;" })
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .Read(read => read.Action("LoadCustomerStatementEnquiryDetails", "Stage").Data("passFilterCstDetails")))
                        )
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
public class StatemenetInquiryParameter
{
    public decimal customerCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime cst_stmt_from { get; set; }
    public DateTime cst_stmt_to { get; set; }
    public bool isPrintZero { get; set; }
    public bool isPrintPayments { get; set; }
    public bool isPrintAdjust { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult LoadCustomerStatementEnquiryDetails([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StatemenetInquiryParameter statemenetInquiryParameter)
    {
        List<CstTran> l = new List<CstTran>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            CstTran c = new CstTran();

            c.cst_inv_date = statemenetInquiryParameter.cst_stmt_from.AddDays(i);
            c.cst_type = "I";
            c.cst_ih_invno = i + 1;
            c.cst_dr_amount = i;
            c.cst_cr_amount = 0;
            c.cst_dr_balance = c.cst_dr_balance + i;

            l.Add(c);
        }

        return Json(l.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Comment: So when you pull the value back from the server is it giving you the 1st of April or the 4th of Jan. If it is 4th of Jan then this a simple "globalization" issue where you have part of your solution translating between something like "en-US" and "en-GB" e.g. MMddyyyy vs ddMMyyyy using this link might help: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem,  i solved it by checking the data format at the time of saving.

1- find the data while saving

```
 var dataS = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
 var updatedData = dataS._data;
```

2- check the format and then save it, my data parameter is rsrc_dt

```
    var dateValue = updatedData[i].rsrc_dt;
    var day; var year; var mon;
    if (typeof dateValue === 'string' || dateValue instanceof String) {
    day = dateValue.split('/')[0];  // use when date is not in correct string format
    mon = dateValue.split('/')[1];
    year = dateValue.split('/')[2];
    var dateS = day + '/' + mon + '/' +year;
    serverData[i].rsrc_dt = dateValue;
    }
    else if (dateValue instanceof Date) {
    var date = new Date(updatedData[i].rsrc_dt);
    year = date.getFullYear();
    day = date.getDate();
    day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day
    mon = date.getMonth();
    mon = mon + 1;
    mon = mon < 10 ? '0' + mon : mon;
    var dateF = day + "/" + mon + "/" + year;
    serverData[i].rsrc_dt = dateF;
    }
```

3- You may try this also, give format of data in field template like this one

```
     { field: "rsrc_dt", title: "Session Date", format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", editor: dateTimeEditor, width: 73, attributes: { "class": "azN" }, },
```

4- Use DateEditor

```
  function dateTimeEditor(container, options) {
  $('<input name="editableBlock" data-text-field="' + options.field +    '" data-value-field="' + options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDatePicker({ min: btch_strt_dt });

}
```