# Getting error message e.slice is not a function while setting data source to kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying fetch data and set that data as datasource of a kendo grid using ajax.

I am getting data properly from controller. But when I am trying yo set data source to kendo grid it's showing me following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function

```js
$(function () {
        loadCstDetails();
    });

function loadCstDetails() {

        var statemenetInquiryParameter = {};

        statemenetInquiryParameter.isPrintZero = true;
        statemenetInquiryParameter.isPrintPayments = true;
        statemenetInquiryParameter.isPrintAdjust = true;
        statemenetInquiryParameter.cst_stmt_from = new Date("April 01, 2016");
        statemenetInquiryParameter.cst_stmt_to = new Date("April 12, 2016");
        statemenetInquiryParameter.customerCode = 007;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ statemenetInquiryParameter: statemenetInquiryParameter }),
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadCustomerStatementEnquiryDetails", "Stage")',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#gridCustomerCstTranDetailsManual').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ServicePROWeb.ServiceProWCFService.CstTran>()
                            .Name("gridCustomerCstTranDetailsManual")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_inv_date).Title("Invoice Date").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Format(Session["DisplayFormat_GridDate"].ToString()).Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_type).Title("Type").Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_ih_invno).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Filterable(false).Title("Invoice Number").Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_dr_amount).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Filterable(false).Title("Debit").Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_cr_amount).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Filterable(false).Title("Credit").Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.cst_dr_balance).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: right;" }).Filterable(false).Title("Balance").Width(80);
                            })
                            .Selectable()
                            .Sortable()
                            .Scrollable()
                            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "cursor:pointer;height:auto;width:auto;margin-top: 0px;" })
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax())
                        )
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
public class StatemenetInquiryParameter
{
    public decimal customerCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime cst_stmt_from { get; set; }
    public DateTime cst_stmt_to { get; set; }
    public bool isPrintZero { get; set; }
    public bool isPrintPayments { get; set; }
    public bool isPrintAdjust { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult LoadCustomerStatementEnquiryDetails([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StatemenetInquiryParameter statemenetInquiryParameter)
    {
        List<CstTran> l = new List<CstTran>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            CstTran c = new CstTran();

            c.cst_inv_date = statemenetInquiryParameter.cst_stmt_from.AddDays(i);
            c.cst_type = "I";
            c.cst_ih_invno = i + 1;
            c.cst_dr_amount = i;
            c.cst_cr_amount = 0;
            c.cst_dr_balance = c.cst_dr_balance + i;

            l.Add(c);
        }

        return Json(l.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

public class CstTran
{
    public decimal cst_cm_code { get; set; }
    public string cst_type { get; set; }
    public DateTime cst_stmt_from { get; set; }
    public int cst_ih_invno { get; set; }
    public int cst_rcpt_no { get; set; }
    public decimal cst_dr_amount { get; set; }
    public decimal cst_cr_amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime cst_inv_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime cst_stmt_to { get; set; }
    public decimal cst_dr_balance { get; set; }
    public int cst_ih_acct_per { get; set; }
    public int cst_lvl4_sequence { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by using `ToDataSourceResult()`. Try to update `LoadCustomerStatementEnquiryDetails()` method as shown below:

```
public JsonResult LoadCustomerStatementEnquiryDetails(StatemenetInquiryParameter statemenetInquiryParameter)
{
    List<CstTran> l = new List<CstTran>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        CstTran c = new CstTran();

        c.cst_inv_date = statemenetInquiryParameter.cst_stmt_from.AddDays(i);
        c.cst_type = "I";
        c.cst_ih_invno = i + 1;
        c.cst_dr_amount = i;
        c.cst_cr_amount = 0;
        c.cst_dr_balance = c.cst_dr_balance + i;

        l.Add(c);
    }
    return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Hıpe this helps...

Answer (score 0):

From just the visual inspection of the provided code I suspect we have two things here.

Firstly:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax())
```

If you are defining a "remote" datasource then you need to provide the command with a **read** action or bind it to a collection (based on my experiences) which is probably what is blowing up the error you are experiencing.

In addition to this you seem to be crafting code that the declaration of the grid can do for you.

If you wish to send some parameters over to the controller then I would suggest altering your code as follows:

```
    .DataSource(dataSource => {
                dataSource.Ajax()
                .Read(read => {
                 read.Action("LoadCustomerStatementEnquiryDetails", "Stage").Data("loadCstDetails");
                              })
```

then alter your existing loadCstDetails function to:

```
function loadCstDetails() {

        var statemenetInquiryParameter = {};

        statemenetInquiryParameter.isPrintZero = true;
        statemenetInquiryParameter.isPrintPayments = true;
        statemenetInquiryParameter.isPrintAdjust = true;
        statemenetInquiryParameter.cst_stmt_from = new Date("April 01, 2016");
        statemenetInquiryParameter.cst_stmt_to = new Date("April 12, 2016");
        statemenetInquiryParameter.customerCode = 007;
   return {statemenetInquiryParameter: statemenetInquiryParameter};
}
```

This should then pass the object as you originally had.

Hopefully this provides you with a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have alreay done that and [facing this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904834/date-format-is-changing-while-fetching-data-using-kendo-grid). Please have a look.